# Problema con el envio de formularios con nodejs

Tags: html, nodejs

Estoy tratando de mandar los valores de un formulario a través de `nodeJS` con el framework `express`.

Tengo algo así en el archivo de inicio `server.js`:

```
const app  = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const express = require("express");
var mysql = require('mysql');

const fs = require("fs");

/* Crear servidor */
http.listen(5000, function() {
  console.log('listening on *:5000');
});


/* index */
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile("./index.html");
});
//Metemos un js funcional independiente

app.get('/funct.js',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile("./funct.js");
});

app.post('/insert_bd', (req, res) => {
    let formNomBD=req.body.bd_nom;
    let formApeBD=req.body.bd_ape;
    let formSApBD=req.body.bd_s_a;

    console.log(formNomBD);
    console.log(formApeBD);
    console.log(formSApBD);
})
```

Y éste es el formulario dentro de `index.html`

```
<form method="post" action="insert_bd">
    <label>Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" name="bd_nom">
    <label>Apellidos:</label>
    <input type="text" name="bd_ape">
    <input type="text" name="bd_s_a">

    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Cada vez que le doy al `submit` salta el mismo error **en el servidor** node:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bd_nom' of undefined
    at app.post (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/server.js:25:25)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/linux3/Escritorio/demo/NODEJS/demo-02/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
0'
```

Tras leer toda la documentación, fijarme bien, y hacer varios ejercicios de ello, me puse con el formulario y no me sale.
¿Por qué no es capaz de leer los valores de los `input` del mismo formulario al que le mando por `action`?

**[EDIT]**

He cambiado en el js del servidor lo siguiente:

```
    let formNomBD=req.body.bd_nom;
    let formApeBD=req.body.bd_ape;
    let formSApBD=req.body.bd_s_a;
```

A esto:

```
    let formNomBD=req.query.bd_nom;
    let formApeBD=req.query.bd_ape;
    let formSApBD=req.query.bd_s_a;
```

Y al menos ya me saca algo, pero es valor `undefined`
Sigo sin entender el por qué pasa...

**[EDIT 2]**

Implementando el código tal y como dijiste:

**index.html**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**server.js**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me sigue saliendo el mismo error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te falta instalar el paquete:

```
npm install --save body-parser
```

Y añadir esto en el `server.js`:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

Para que procese el body de la petición.

EDIT:

Poniendo el bodyParser, ya llega el body:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No, acabo de probarlo, cuando hago el request del body, simplemente añadiendo eso, me salta el error de que `body´ no está definido. Por el contrario, si pongo `bodyParser´ me salta el error de que no puede capturar el valor bd_nom

Comment: ¿Donde estas poniendo el bodyParser? Lo he montado en plan rápido y me funciona, he editado la respuesta para que lo veas

Comment: Pues así lo puse yo y no me funcionaba, voy a volver a probar a ver...

Comment: Vale, ya conseguí que me funcionara, solamente cambié el nombre del formulario, al parecer, en mi máquina, por alguna razón, no puedo poner un guión bajo ( _ ) . Por lo tanto cambié el nombre tanto del formulario como del app.post a insertDb y ya me funciona

Comment: A partir de Express 4.17 en adelante, no hace falta el paquete `body-parser`, ya que viene integrado con Express: `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true /* o false */}));` y tambien: `app.use(express.json());`. Saludos